# Copy the widths of images to clipboard (Mac)

Tags: mac, finder, clipboard, image-editing

I have a bunch of images in a folder and would like an easy way to either copy all of the widths to the clipboard or export them to a document. I know I can Get Info and copy it from the window that pops up, but that's way too time-consuming with the number of images I'm working with.

Any suggestions on a way to speed this up or automate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Mac OSX has the `file` command as on Linux it can output image info, eg:

```
$ file out.png
out1.png: PNG image data, 542 x 149, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

or you can use ImageMagick which has a command too:

```
$ identify out1.png
out1.png PNG 542x149 542x149+0+0 8-bit sRGB 11.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000

$ identify -format '%f: %w\n' *.png *.jpg
out1.png: 542
out3.jpg: 1134
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked! for anyone else, I used:
file format '%f: %w\n' *.png *.jpg

on the folder, and it returned info on all of the images within. I can easily get just the widths now.